# Error al sincronizar datos con Cloud Firestore cuando cierran la aplicación

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firestore

Estoy trabajando con react-native expo y firestore, todo parecía estar funcionando bien, cuando noto algo extraño, el problema es este, según la documentación me dice esto.

```
En las plataformas Android y Apple, la persistencia sin conexión está 
habilitada de manera predeterminada. Para deshabilitar la persistencia, 
establezca la opción PersistenceEnabled en falso.
```

Cuando realizo un cambio sin conexión mientras la aplicación está abierta y me vuelvo a conectar a Internet, los datos se sincronizan perfectamente.

El problema es cuando realizo un cambio fuera de línea y cierro la aplicación, mientras la aplicación está completamente cerrada, me conecto a Internet y entro en la aplicación, se supone que los datos creados anteriormente mientras estaba fuera de línea se actualizan en firestore, pero firestore no lo está haciendo, es como si nunca lo hubiera escrito.

esta es mi configuración de base de fuego
versión: "^9.18.0"

```
 import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
 import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

 const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "MY.APIKEY",
   authDomain: "MY.DOMAIN",
   projectId: "MY.PROJECT",
   storageBucket: "MY.STORAGE",
   messagingSenderId: "MY.MESSAGIN",
   appId: "MY.APPID",
 };

 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const database = getFirestore(app);

 export { database };
```

Este es la escritura de datos

```
 import { arrayUnion, arrayRemove, doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
 import { database } from "../database/firebase";

 const onSubmitEdit = async(data) => {
   const userRef = doc(database, "users", email);
   await updateDoc(userRef, { groups: arrayUnion(data) });
   await updateDoc(userRef, { groups: arrayRemove(route.params.item) });
 };

 const onSubmitCreate = async(data) => {
   const userRef = doc(database, "users", email);

   await updateDoc(userRef, { groups: arrayUnion(data) });
 };
```

Este es mi onSnapshot

```
 import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
 import { database } from "../database/firebase";

 const session = useSelector((state) => state.session);
 const activeGroup = useSelector((state) => state.activeGroup);

 useEffect(() => {
   if (session) {
     const snap = onSnapshot(
       doc(database, "users", email),
       { includeMetadataChanges: true },
       async(doc) => {
         /* TASKS */
       }
     );
     return() => {
       snap();
     };
   }
 }, [activeGroup.active, session]);
```

Intenté eliminar el includeMetadataChanges incluso colocando el onSnapshot sin las limitaciones del useEffect, pero nada funciona, cambié la configuración y probé algunos códigos de firebase y tampoco funciona, nada funciona :,(

Espero me puedan ayudar, tengo 4 dias en este problema :,(